# Cant get theme to change footer color through theme customizer

Tags: php, functions, css, html, theme-customizer

I am having an issue trying to configure the theme I am working on to allow the footer color to be changed. So far all of my other options work so I am geussing it is an issue with the way I am calling back to the css class.

This is the footer class:

```
 .footer {
 background: #f7f7f7;
 height: 150px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 7;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 -ms-box-shadow: 0 2px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 -o-box-shadow: 0 2px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
```

}

This is how I am calling it from the theme:

```
 function theme_header_css() {
 ?>

   <style>

       .footer {
        background: <?php echo my_theme_mod( 'hero_footer_color' ); ?>;
        }

   </style

  <?php
  }
  add_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_header_css' );
```

I tried calling background-color instead of background but that doesn't seem to work. I am thinking that I am not calling the class right. Can anyone give me a hand?

**EDIT:** When I check the page CSS I can see that it is attempting to override the background color, although it is not producing a value and appears like this:

.footer {
            background: ;
            }

After checking through multiple times it is the proper setting, so I am at a loss to what it is, if it is not the CSS.

**Here is get_theme_mods()**

```
 function my_get_theme_mods() {
$defaults = array(      
    'my_hero_title'                 => '',
    'my_hero_description'           => '',      
    'my_hero_background_color'      => '#17649a',
    'my_hero_background_image'      => '',
    'my_hero_background_repeat'     => 'no-repeat',
    'my_hero_background_position'   => 'center',        
    'my_footer_color'               => '#f7f7f7',
);

return $defaults;
```

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem might be without seeing my_theme_mod() at least.

Comment: does the style code appear in the head section?

Comment: Perhaps instead of 'my_theme_mod' you should try the get_theme_nod() function?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I have made an addition to my post, Michael, no the style isn't in the head section. @WPMU-DEVAri Ari - I have just tried that with the same outcome. I am going to add in the my_theme_mod settings into my post.

Comment: @vancoder , Thanks I have added in the my_theme_mod.

Comment: You added the my_get_theme_mods() function. We'll also need to see the my_theme_mod() function.